# RxSwift: how to get rid of callback hells of subscribe events and network request?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

RxSwift: how to get rid of callback hells of subscribe events and network request?

I am a new Swifter, Here is the code of my new company.

The following code is very wired.

The logic is easy . BoutiqueOutput has a requestCommand,which is PublishSubject. It is  used to do some refresh thing (request the network initailly and again ).

The callback hell is in it. The network layer Moya was used in a RxSwift way.

New to RxSwift , I do not know the pattern to refactor it nicely.

How to use filter/ map / combine operators in the right way?

This is the model encapulated with RxSwift

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import RxDataSources
import MJRefresh
import Moya
import MoyaMapper


// this is the Moya Network Provider
let Provider = MoyaProvider<Router>(endpointClosure: EndpointClosure, requestClosure: requestClosure, plugins: [networkPlugin, MoyaMapperPlugin(NetParameter())], trackInflights: false)


struct BoutiqueOutput: OutputRefreshProtocol {

    var refreshStatus = Variable<RefreshStatus>(.none)

    let sections: Driver<[CategoryLeftSection]>

    let requestCommand = PublishSubject<Bool>()
    init(sections: Driver<[CategoryLeftSection]>) {
        self.sections = sections
    }
}


class CategoryViewModel: NSObject {

    let vmDatas = Variable<[ParentItem]>([])

    func transform() -> BoutiqueOutput {

        let tempSections = vmDatas.asObservable().map({ (sections) -> [CategoryLeftSection] in
            return [CategoryLeftSection(items: sections)]
        }).asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])

        let output = BoutiqueOutput(sections: tempSections)
        output.requestCommand.subscribe(onNext:{[weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            Provider.rx.cacheRequest(.baseUIData).subscribe( onNext:{ result in
                // do some UI 
                if result.statusCode == 200 || result.statusCode == 230 {
                    // do something business
                } 

            }).disposed(by: self.rx.disposeBag)
        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
        return output
    }
}
```

This is how the model applied

```
private var vmOutput: BoutiqueOutput?


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.vmOutput = viewModel.transform()
        boundTableViewData()
    // ...
}


private func boundTableViewData() {

    let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<CategoryLeftSection>( configureCell: { [weak self] ds, tv, ip, item in
     // ...
     }


  vmOutput!.sections.asDriver().drive(self.leftMenuTableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource)).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

     // ...

    vmOutput!.requestCommand.onNext(true)

}



private func requestErrorRefresh() {
     // ...
     if isNetworkConnect {
           boundTableViewData()
           vmOutput!.requestCommand.onNext(true)
     }
}


private func noNetworkRefresh() {
     // ...
     if isNetworkConnect {
           boundTableViewData()
           vmOutput!.requestCommand.onNext(true)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `combineLatest` operator to solve this problem.

Here is the code:

```
let output = BoutiqueOutput(sections: temp_sections)
Observable.combineLatest(output.requestCommand, Provider.rx.cacheRequest(.baseUIData)).subscribe({  [weak self]  ( result: Event<(Bool, Response)>) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result{
            case .next(let response):
                // do some UI 
                if result.statusCode == 200 || result.statusCode == 230 {
                     // do something business
                } 
            default:
                break
            }
        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```

`combineLatest`: Merges the specified observable sequences into one observable sequence of tuples whenever any of the observable sequences produces an element.

It is nice to combine two irrelevant events together, and do something common.

> By the way: I think it two days and don't know how to solve it . And I
>   listed systematically and posted here, after some time, I figured it
>   out. Interesting experience.